# Is it possible to lock a record and still allow other users to read it?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, record-locking

This might be a very dumb question, but as the saying goes, "The only dumb question is the one you don't ask"...

I've got a SQL Server 2008 database and I want to lock a record for editing.  However, another user might want to see information in that record at the same time.  So, I want the first person in to be able to lock the record in the sense that they are the only ones who can edit it.  However, I still want other users to see the data if they want to.

This is all done from a C# front end as it's gonna be on our Intranet.

Comment: What do you mean by lock for editing? is it a simple locking for duration of an update (few miliseconds) or you want to lock for the time when user is editing the text fields of that entity (might never end)?

Comment: Just until it's committed.  I think marc_s gave me a good explanation, so I'm going to move forward with that info.

Comment: This statement: `I want the first person in to be able to edit the record` makes it sound like you're talking about user authentication rather than DB row-locking.

Comment: @ebyrob - Not authentication, because it doesn't matter who that first person is.  I just want more than one person to be able to view it, while only the first person to open it (whoever it happens to be) is the only person who can edit the record.

Comment: @JohnnyBones Oh ok, `first person **in**` for that iteration.  I'd mis-read the re-read.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do your own locking - let SQL Server handle it on its own.

As long as you only `SELECT`, you'll put what's called a **shared** lock on a row - other users who want to also read that row can do so.

Only when your code goes to **update** the row, it will place an **exclusive** lock on the row in order to be able to update it. During that period of time, no other users can read that one single row you're updating - until you commit your transaction.

Comment: Ya, it goes without saying, you want to turn on transaction mode (instead of auto-commit) if this type of issue is of any concern.

Comment: @ebyrob: no necessarily - if you don't do explicit transactions, then each T-SQL statement runs in its own, implicit transaction.

Comment: I don't recall all the vagaries of T-SQL transactions, but I *do* remember that auto-commit was generally a scary and unpredictable place to be when I last worked on it.  (implicit transactions still get committed more or less manually auto-commit is quite different, and messier, than that)

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Marc_s's answer, the *reader* can also use the

```
set transaction isolation Level read uncommitted
```

statement [as described here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) to force reads to ignore any locks (with the notable exception of any **Sch-M**, schema modification, locks) that may exist. This is also a useful setting for reports that do not require absolute reproducibility, as it can significantly enance performance of those reports.for

Comment: (a) be aware that you *might* be reading data that doesn't get committed to the database in the end! And also: (b) it doesn't help for **all** locks - if you have a `Sch-M` (schema modification) lock, then the `READ UNCOMMITTED` will still be stopped and won't actually read the data...

Comment: @marc_s: I usually assume that *Sch-M* locks are very rare in a production database. In a ledger-based accounting package, situation (a) is also unusual if not exactly rare.

Comment: True - I just couldn't resist since you wrote *ignore **any** locks that may exist* - that's a bit too optimistic - it will ignore **most** locks ....

Comment: @marc_s: Thank you - new improved answer now available. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the existing answers: You can enable snapshot isolation. That gives your transaction a point-in-time snapshot of the database for reads. This transaction will not take locks on data at all. It will not block.